# best component for showing messages (text with image) in c++ builder (Xe8)

Tags: c++builder, firemonkey

I am making a chat application as a project in firemonkey. I am looking for a component/control to show chat msgs. I tried to find alternative to `TRichEdit`, but I couldnt. Should I use TListView(didnt try it), or something else would be better ?

One more thing I also want store and retrieve chat msgs into a file in this application.this wont be stored in main server. So what type of file would be efficient, word/pdf/something else ? So someone please guide me. Any kind of help is appreciable.